# Reading .txt file in Python given a data structure

Tags: python, text

I have a text file that I am trying to read in Python. Here is the first line:

```
first_line = (f.readline())
first_line
```

**Output:**  `'P,5.000000,5.000000,15.000000,60.000000,5.000000,15.000000,60.000000,-20.000000,-0.000000,-4.000000,-10.000000,-3.000000,-24.000000,-0.000000,0.000000,0,0.200000,20.000000,1.000000\n'`

I have the following description for this line which I do not know what language was used. Can you please help me create each number as a parameter with the associated names below?

```
str_Input_Data += "P," +
to_string(_IHVS_MINIMUM_ACTIVITY_DURATION ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_START_LOW ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_START_MEDIUM ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_START_HIGH ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_DURATION_LOW ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_DURATION_MEDIUM ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_FLEXIBILITY_DURATION_HIGH ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_AV_FIXED ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_PARKING_PER_HOUR ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_AV_ENERGY_PER_HOUR ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_VALUE_OF_TIME_PER_HOUR ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_TAXI_FIXED ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_TAXI_PER_HOUR ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_ZOV_TAX_PER_HOUR ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_COST_ZOV_TAX_FIXED ) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_GENERATE_VISUALIZATION_FILE) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_MIPGAP) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_TIMEOUT) + "," +
to_string(_IHVS_THREAD) +
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you want is to just read in the line and do `.split(',')` on it, to turn it into a list of strings that were separated by commas, rather than a single string. The `csv` module might also be able to help you, so look into it

Comment: is the description line in the same file as the data or elsewhere? that code block could be valid python

Comment: You could also take a look at `pandas` but it might be a bit overkill for this kind of parsing, `csv` is easier to use for simple purpose.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thanks for the hint. split worked like a champ.